# Return index of clicked element in an array and make that the value of a variable outside?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, scope, closures

Ok so this my code right now:

```
(function slideshow(){

   var arr = [first, second, third, forth];
   for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      arr[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
         alert(i);
      });
   }

   var d = 0;

}());
```

What I've been trying to do for the last hour and failing miserably, is for `i` to be the index of the clicked element in the array. Right now `alert(i)` always return `4` instead of the index number of the clicked element.

The other thing I want to happen is to have that value (the indexOf the clicked element) to become the value of `d`, which is outside the for loop.

ie. `d=0` by default until you click `arr[i]` then `d = i`. Any ideas how I'd go about doing that?

Comment: The reason it is always showing 4 is because your loop always finishes before a click event happens, and when your loop finishes the value of `i` is 4. So I suggest you to create a promise type implementation, basically assign unique `id`s to every element yourself and after the click trigger, get the element id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `i` is the value that `i` has after the `for` loop. `0` to `3` are your indexes and `4` is the value that exited of the loop because it's larger than your array length.

What you need to do is to actually have a value stored in `first`, `second`, etc. that you can grab.

You could store the actual value of `i` inside the element:

```
var arr = [first, second, third, forth];
for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   arr[i].setAttribute('data-index', i);
   arr[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
      alert(this.getAttribute('data-index'));
   });
}
```